# Initializing Braintree payments on the client side with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, braintree

I am attempting to initialize the Braintree JS SDK on the client side after generating the client token.

The code from their documentation states to use the following:

```
braintree.setup("CLIENT-TOKEN-FROM-SERVER", "custom", {id: "checkout"});
```

The client token is grabbed and put into the scope in the Angular controller and I have attempted to insert it into the client side by using:

```
<script>
        braintree.setup({{ braintreeToken }}, "custom", {id: "checkout"});
</script>
```

However, I receive the following error when loading the page:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve or work around this issue?

**Note**: There are no issues with the client token. It appears to be a string and I can display it on the page normally.

Comment: I don't know that {{ }} works inside script tags. Can anyone confirm/deny?

Comment: Probably it should be `setup("{{ braintreeToken }}", "custom"`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I've attempted that already but receive another error: `Uncaught Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken is not valid JSON.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`braintree.setup` is being invoked before Angular can evaluate the value of braintreeToken. You could include the call to `braintree.setup` inside your Angular controller so braintreeToken is available to be passed in. Here's a generic way to solve it with Angular:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
    $http.post('/someUrlThatProvidesYourClientToken', {customer_id: 'some-id'})
      .then(function(token) {
        braintree.setup(token, "custom", {id: "checkout"});
      }, function(err) {
        // Do something with error
      });
}]);
```